# OSMC has mounted 2 versions of my External HD

Tags: usb, mount, raspbian-jessie

After a reboot OSMC has mounted my External HD with 2 versions. The original has become `externalHD_` from `externalHD` and I can no longer access it. Why are there 2 and how do I prevent this?

```
osmc@osmc:/media$ ls
externalHD  externalHD_
osmc@osmc:/media$ cd externalHD
-bash: cd: externalHD: Permission denied
```

Here is what happens when I list it:

```
osmc@osmc:/media$ ls
externalHD  externalHD_
osmc@osmc:/media$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Jan  1  1970 ..
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Jan  1  1970 externalHD
drwxrwxrwx  6  999  999 4096 Feb 28 06:46 externalHD_
```

I can unmount it. go root, delete the `externalHD` unplug the HD, reboot then reattach it. However I don't want to have to do this everytime.

When I enter the command `mount`

```
osmc@osmc:~$ mount
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,stripe=1024,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs     (rw,relatime,size=376916k,nr_inodes=94229,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts     (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup     (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-    agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup     (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup     (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup     (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup     (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup     (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs     (rw,relatime,fd=21,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat     (rw,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,err    ors=remount-ro)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /media/externalHD_ type ext4     (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs     (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=76244k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)


GNU nano 2.2.6             File: /etc/fstab                                
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot    vfat     defaults,noatime    0   0
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /    ext4      defaults,noatime    0   0
UUID=1ed5602e-40c5-482f-a3c0-e97c0fd12b20  /media/externalHD    defaults     0     2
```

Now the Pi won't boot after a restart. What's the fault and can I amend it?

Comment: Edit in the output from `mount` (with no options, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: type mount at the command prompt then edit your question and copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

mount only shows `/dev/sda1` mounted on `/media/externalHD_`
The `/media` directory has 2 sub-directories `externalHD` and  `externalHD_` which could be used as `mount points`.

How are you mounting the drive? The GUI mounts in `/media`, and creates mount points, so it may have created a few.

Unless you want transient mounts (in the GUI) you may be better to create an entry in `/etc/fstab`. If so list this, and we can help.

Comment: It mounts in the OSMC GUI. I would like it to always mount at the same point as that's where I point the torrents and nzb files as well as OSMC to update the library. I'd like it to be `/media/externalHD` and NOT `/media/externalHD_`

Comment: I do not use OSMC and have no knowledge of it, or how it mounts media. Regardless it is possible to create an entry in `/etc/fstab` which would mount it in `/media/externalHD`. This could be at boot or when manually set. You could just eject the disk, and delete the unwanted mount point.

Comment: It's based on Debian Jessie. It's the Open Source Media Centre that's taken over from Raspbmc

Comment: Millways is correct -- it's not mounted twice, there are just two directories in `/media`.  You could try unmounting it and removing the drive, then delete both directories and plug it back in and see what happens (maybe you have to reboot).  If it doesn't automount, as root create `/etc/externalHD` and `chmod 777 /etc/externalHD` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Change `fstab` entries to:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot    vfat     defaults,noatime    0   0
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /    ext4      defaults,noatime    0   0
UUID=15c34a6b-f0af-4d24-b546-0eaeaec9ee33  /media/externalHD    ext4      nofail,defaults    0  0
```

This did the trick!

Comment: Please note that the mounting of removable drives that might be not present during boot time with `fstab` is an issue. If the drive it missing the boot process might stop during the attempted mounting. The use of the `nofail` option could help around this. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14365/mount-an-external-drive-at-boot-time-only-if-it-is-plugged-in